# How to set .Net 4.0 as the default framework in MonoDevelop (Unity 3D)

Tags: .net, mono, unity-game-engine

I'm using MonoDevelop version 2.8.2 and the default parameters that are available in the .NET 4.0 framework. My first problem was that every time I reloaded MD the .NET runtime would be reset to 3.0, and I would have to change it again. This wasn't too annoying, but I do also want to know why that kept happening and how I might permanently set it.

My real issue now is that the **.NET Runtime** (or whatever it specifically was, I can't remember) under the **Options** dropdown no longer appears. Instead, I see a disabled **Project Options**.

(I'd put an image of what I see here, but apparently I need reputation.)

If even one of these issues is fixed, I should be fine. But right now I can't rely on the errors messages from the IDE, and have to switch back to Unity.

Comment: No, you can't. Unity use Mono, not Microsoft .NET Framework. Even it's possible, I would not suggest you to do that.

Answer (score 3):

Unity3D v4.2 is currently using Mono v2.6 or so, and only supports equivalent .NET versions of 3.5 or lower. I don't believe it even supports all corners of .NET 3.5 either.

Officially Unity only supports .NET 2.0. [See the supported functions here.](http://docs.unity3d.com/412/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoCompatibility.html)

The best you can do is change the API Compatibility Level from **v2.0-subset** to **v2.0** [in Player Settings](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/class-PlayerSettings.html).